# How to remove extraneous values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, outliers

I have temperature data from 5 different temperature loggers on 5 different reefs recording temperature in degrees Celsius at 1 hour intervals. These loggers are known to make occasional extraneous measurements, and some are apparent in the data when plotted. My question is, what is an effective way to detect and remove these measurements? There are over 7,000 measurements so a manual approach is not feasible (or if it is I'd rather learn a more efficient way of doing it anyways). Another complication is that temperature rose considerably during the duration of tracking; such that an unrealistically high measurement towards the beginning could be quite reasonable towards the end, making the use a stationary temperature cut off also not a workable solution.

My first thought was that I could have a running mean temperature for all 5 receivers combined at 12 hour intervals (arbitrary interval, could just as easily be at 1 day intervals) and then exclude all values that are more than 2 degrees (also arbitrary) away from this running mean based on the assumption that they should all be recording very similar temperatures. The problem is I'm not sure how to create a sequence of intervals in the POSIXct format that I could loop through for something like this, or how to get a combined mean for the different loggers during such an interval in an efficient way. Below is a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
> dput(head(final,10))
structure(list(Date_Time = structure(c(1458635007, 1458635011, 
1458638607, 1458642207, 1458645807, 1458649407, 1458653007, 1458656607, 
1458660207, 1458663807), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
Temp = c(22.369, NA, 22.13, 21.867, 22.058, 22.992, 19.603, 
18.937, 19.413, 20.15), logger = c("R05", "R05", "R05", "R05", 
"R05", "R05", "R05", "R05", "R05", "R05")), .Names = c("Date_Time", 
"Temp", "logger"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

[I also linked an image of a plot of the full data set to show the crazy measurements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6Ug.png).
Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else I should include in the question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: you may get a better answer at stats.stackexchange - it seems the question is really a statistics one rather than programming per se

Comment: I don't know exactly what your data is, but since you are looking at a binary outcome of: whether or not it is extraneous, you can look into a logistic regression model to filter out certain data (there is going to be error). Create the model on a smaller subset and run it on the full set, the set that has a very low probability which you can set, you then take out of the dataset.